# How to draw transparent image with html5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency

I am targeting google chrome.  Is it possible to draw transparent images on a canvas?  By transparent I mean the drawing the entire image at something like 50% opacity.

Comment: Are you wanting the canvas to be transparent so that you can place it over other elements?

Comment: No, it's not possible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-element

Comment: Justin, no I want to draw a semi transparent image on top of other canvas element.  I have no interest in making the entire canvas transparent.

Intelekshual, setting context.globalAlpha effects subsequent context.drawImages atleast in Chrome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The canvas element has a global alpha attribute that lets you apply partial transparency to anything you draw.

Comment: @Mr. Bell: +1 to Chrome for that.

Comment: Link is broken. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-globalalpha

Comment: like this: `ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5`

Answer (score 23):

You can do this using the globalAlpha property, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas height="100" width="100" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
            var myImage = new Image();
            myImage.src = "someImage.jpg";
            myImage.onload = function()
            {
                context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 100, 100);
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And yes, it does work with images.  Verified with IE 9, FF 5, Safari 5, and Chrome 12 on Win 7.

Comment: `globalAlpha` will not work for images drawn with `drawImage` in Firefox 30+: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1028288

Comment: @Derek, this bug only concerns svg images.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible if you iterate thru the canvas' image-data and set the alpha value manually, then export the transparent image with the canvas.toDataURL method and insert it into another canvas.

Comment: You don't have to call toDataURL if you want to draw a canvas on an other, `drawImage` accepts canvas as imageSource.