# Fade an image in

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to fade an image in a canvas environment. Essientially what I want to do is while moving an image from left to right, I want to fade it from 0% alpha to 100% alpha. When I comment the globalAlpha and alpha info out in my code, it moves like I want it to, my only issue is getting it to fade. I am able to get the globalAlpha function to work, but it affects all the artwork in the canvas area. Is there a way I can just affect the one element? eventually I will want to fade in multiple elements at different times in the animation based on a timer, but if I can get this to work first I can go from there.

```
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
function eventWindowLoaded() 
{
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasSupport () 
{
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}
function canvasApp()
    {
        if (!canvasSupport()) 
        {
            return;
        }



        var pointImage = new Image();
        pointImage.src = "images/barry.png";
        var barry = new Image();
        barry.src = "images/barry.png";
        /*var alpha = 0;
        context.globalAlpha = 1;*/

        function drawScreen() 
        {

            //context.globalAlpha = 1;
            context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
            //context.globalAlpha = alpha;

            //Box
            context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            context.strokeRect(1, 1, theCanvas.width-2, theCanvas.height-2);


            if (moves > 0 ) 
            {
                moves--;
                ball.x += xunits;
                ball.y += yunits;
            }



            context.drawImage(barry, ball.x, ball.y);

            /*context.restore();
            alpha += .1;
            if (alpha > 1)
            {
                alpha = 0;
            }*/


        }

        var speed = 1;
        var p1 = {x:20,y:250};
        var p2 = {x:40,y:250};
        var dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        var dy = p2.y - p1.y;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        var moves = distance/speed;
        var xunits = (p2.x - p1.x)/moves;
        var yunits = (p2.y - p1.y)/moves;
        var ball = {x:p1.x, y:p1.y};
        var points = new Array();
        theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
        setInterval(drawScreen, 10);
    }
```

any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Any reason in particular you are not using jQuery?

Comment: Can you set the context to the one area and then modify the alpha?

Comment: know jQuery is the way to go, guess for learning purposes I am trying to get in and learn as much from a coding stance as I can... but jQuery is definately on the horizon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this other question will give you a way to do so.

it shows how to load an element in the canvas context then how to fade it in..

[How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen)