# HTML5 - Change opacity of a draw Rectangle

Tags: html, canvas

Let's say I draw an HTML5 element of rectangle using this:

```
context.clearRect(25, 72, 32, 32);
```

How would I make it 50% transparent?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use globalAlpha. You'll also have to draw with fillRect. clearRect just erases pixels. It can't partially erase so you'll have to use fillRect or other drawing primitives.

from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_globalalpha.asp):

```
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    ctx.fillRect(50,50,75,50);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
```

Comment: This makes the whole canvas transparent (on Chrome atleast)

Comment: Brian, it doesn't clear the whole canvas, only the size and location you give it. That's what those 4 numbers are; the first two being the X coordinate on the canvas, then the Y coord., and then the size X and Y of the rect you'd like to clear. 
(Keep in mind that Y values instead get bigger as they go down, in Canvas)

Comment: Note that you'll need to call `ctx.globalAlpha=1;` after those two lines in order to prevent further draw calls (even previous ones, believe it or not) from being partially transparent as well.

Comment: You'll also need to be sure to call `clearRect` before all drawing occurs or else you'll end up with a "trailing effect" (unless that's what you're intending to do -- kinda neat looking).

Answer (score 69):

ClearRect removes what was there and leaves it blank. The best way is to use a rgba fillStyle value as it will only make the rectangle (or any other shape that you are drawing) transparent. The code would be:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(225,225,225,0.5)';
ctx.fillRect(25,72,32,32);
```

(thanks [How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen))

Comment: I prefer this over the selected answer since it doesn't globally effect all drawing after using it.

Comment: You can save and restore the context so that it doesn't take affect globally by using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` wrapped around your other context changes.

Comment: I prefer this over the most popular because it is more concrete:  talks about the transparency of the fill (I want to 'clean' a rectangle), not the transparency of any operation.   The two solutions requires 4 lines (because the ctx.save() and ctx.restore() to preserve context).  Anyway, the two solutions are good for me.