# Background image fade out in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the background .gif fade out after 8s. 7s later a text and a button should appear. Everything seems to be working so far however, the text and button seems to fade out along with the background. It looks like it may be the way I set up the html but I was wondering if there was a way around this if using just jQuery and maybe barely just touching with the html? Suggestions welcomed thanks in advance!

```js
// Hide DISPIRIT text then fade in
$(".brand-heading").hide().delay(7000).fadeIn("slow");
$(".btn-circle").hide().delay(7000).fadeIn("slow");
// BG delay then fade out
$(".intro-body").delay(8000).fadeOut("slow");
```

```css
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.intro .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(../img/static.gif) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  /*.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 26px;
      }*/
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100% !important;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="intro">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h1 class="brand-heading"><i>Dispirit</i></h1>
          <p class="intro-text"></p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You are calling `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` on the jQuery object, not the `background-image` set at CSS. It is not possible, that am aware of, to set the `opacity` of a `background-image` set at CSS. You can set the `opacity` of the `DOM` element.

Comment: Seconded^. You're fading out `.intro-body` using jQuery, which is hiding the entire element and everything contained in it - pretty much all your content. You'll have to touch the HTML a bit.

Comment: @JonUleis The requirement apparently is possible using `<canvas>` `CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalAlpha [ = value ]`,  `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` method, and `requestAnimationFrame()` and `setTimeout()`

Comment: @JonUleis At least a Chrome, Chromium browsers, Firefox does not render expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/h72uvm4h/1/

```js
// Hide DISPIRIT text then fade in
$('.container').hide().delay(7000).fadeIn("slow");
// BG delay then fade out
$(".intro-body").delay(8000).fadeOut("slow");
```

```css
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.intro .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: url(../img/static.gif) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.container {
  display:none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .intro {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  /*.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 26px;
      }*/
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 100% !important;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="intro">
  <div class="intro-body">
  
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1 class="brand-heading"><i>Dispirit</i></h1>
        <p class="intro-text"></p>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I have changed the `HTML` structure a bit, because if you hide the **parent** **container** you won't be able to see the **child** **elements**.

I took out the **container class** out of **intro-body** and set `display: none;` initially using `CSS` & `jQuery`.

Hope this will solve you problem.

Comment: Hey thanks! This helped a ton. I had to create another div in place of the <div class="container"> cuz it messed with all my containers. Then instead of display: none; I used the display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

Comment: @Shiladitya JavaScript at Question does not fade the `background-image` at CSS

Comment: @guest271314 .. I know, it's fading the container (div)

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for rendering a `background-image` fade effect is to draw the image to a `<canvas>` element, call `canvasContext2d.globalAlpha` as described at [How to change the opacity (alpha, transparency) of an element in a canvas element after it has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359537/how-to-change-the-opacity-alpha-transparency-of-an-element-in-a-canvas-elemen), call `canvas.drawImage()` then set the resulting `data URI` at CSS `url()` function for the element within function passed to `requestAminationFrame` where `requestAnimationFrame` is called again within function passed to `setTimeout()`

```js
onload = function() {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const div = document.querySelector("div");
  const img = new Image;
  const duration = 50;
  let fader, image;

  function fx(n) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = n === undefined ? ctx.globalAlpha - 0.01 : n;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    image = canvas.toDataURL();
    div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
  }

  function step() {
    if (ctx.globalAlpha.toFixed(2) > 0.01) {
      fx();
      if (ctx.globalAlpha === 0.009999999999999247) {
        fx(0);
      };
      setTimeout(function() {
        fader = requestAnimationFrame(step)
      }, duration);
    } else {
      console.log("complete", ctx.globalAlpha);
      cancelAnimationFrame(fader);
    }
  }

  img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight
    div.style.width = img.naturalWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = img.naturalHeight + "px";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    image = canvas.toDataURL();
    div.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
    fader = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }

  img.src = `data:image/jpeg;charset=binary;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAQDAwMDAgQDAwMEBAQFBgoGBgUFBgwICQcKDgwPDg4MDQ0PERYTDxAVEQ0NExoTFRcYGRkZDxIbHRsYHRYYGRj/2wBDAQQEBAYFBgsGBgsYEA0QGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBj/wAARCAFUAfsDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQABAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICf/EAEIQAAEEAQMCBAQEBAQEBQQDAAEAAgMRBAUSITFBBhNRYQcicYEUMpGhI0Kx0RVSwfAkM2JyCBZDY+E0kqLxU3Oy/8QAGgEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBv/EACYRAQEBAAICAgEDBQEAAAAAAAABEQIDITEEElEFE0EiMlJhcbH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AP5/oiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiLNsMjmbmscRVmh0CDBFSCOyiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiUrSCIsqVpFxhSyAVpVTTGNJ3WSiKKIlIIoFlSiqIitKIgiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiIKOvRet8NZOFpeF/iuXDHkhr9kUBPJPe/ZeRXYRvc3To2uNjcSK7KUfStMyvh54niZjeINEyNKfuEYztOIfsvgEsPJ7mvZdN41+E2ueFdObrmBNFrnh6Q/JqeCCWx/9Mresbvrx7rzOP5sZbKaa08h1dPoQvqfw8+IWreE8+PFknhy8LIO2aDIDZop21+R3N9OKIU3FvG+4+IovuHxK+F2i6l4cn+IvwxZu0yIb9U0dhL34BJ/5sf+aE/q3vx0+IFpbV9xa0iIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIrSCIrSu1FxiizpWlNMYUqAsg2zwrtpNMYgK1SvQKKKqdkRBEQ9UQFFUQRFUQRRXuorBEVKiqIitKIgiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgLlh3/AAsY6Dn+q4i5AJ/Dxi/VSrHZacwSSEXIZAPkaxm6z788Bd+PPihcxz4h5lBzJDEXE+vqPra8tC8tNgmj6L0WDBp+XitvHkdOBXyPbG0nsTfUdbPCxXXjfD23gnxvqnhLVWz4cheyJ1Oikb8sjCfmjf2IPr37rj/FnwFoccJ8deAoyPD2S9seVgA27Sslwvyz/wC043tPQdPRefaxwfG3H06EFjL3QTtLnN9bHX7r2/gHxxHp+vnR9dhZPoepxnBzsVwBaYyPlvr0I4Pa69Elxjlx3zHwj2Re4+J3w/yPAfi12PDL+L0fLb+I07OZy2aI9r/zNuiPa+68P3XRgREpARWkpBEVAVpFxilLKlaQxjSUs6SlNXGNK17LKhaVwmmMdqu1ZIpoxrhWgqtuPjzZWSzHx43SyvNNY0WSg1hpJAAte68OfDTUdVhbmavkt0nDdRBe3dLIPRre3rZIXe+EPDeDokEudqccM+cYjtjlHDHdg336c8+y9JqmoyZcsj8vyTlzFvmObKBEQ0/lJ9elgcpqeXCj+H/w2MEuO3N1gvhjDnznb14/lr0Xznxj4Qn8M5UcjZDkYGQScfIAoOA/lI7OHcL38OoxNyG7XOiePn8tjgwOrpyLIHTjm65K5uqx4viX4Ha/hiOdmdps7dYjc/5hQGyWME8hux99TyxNT0+FFSlkeCVijSKqd0QFUUQEROhQERS0FUpFUGKKqLQKFZKIMUQojIiIgtIQsqSlNXGCLKkpUxiiypKpDGKLKlKQxEVpWkMYosiEpDGKK0lIYiK0lIYi3g/8M0+hIWmluYCYCPdCN8Aa+Roe4tb3IFrvJM+OZn4duLJM1jKsnqR3IHX7/suig5O3cAOriejfdctuQ95EGOHiMNFkCyR7nt9lnGpcegizpp4gw4uSch/NMlDrY0AAFoHygV1Jpc6bC1bHjMk2kxB23eXefG8tHUFpDrBrm+i63TS5+SMTHgfM6Y7fw8TQN/qS67P34XoJcTKgzpZIIcIVf8EbXyNA7HrdDv8Asphr1/hOfC8e+Apvh/4gyoWiR5dgZ8vyHEnAJD39qcaa6jyOeoXxbxH4b1Twvr0+javiSY2dBI6KWJw5BBrj1B6g9xS9Jg5udp3iVuTgQtjkJDg2MAtLvdnYHmx78L7Preg4fxq+HLdXjEeP4p0eER5QsHzILpjie5bw0nrVFJf4Tl71+XaSl3+t+FtX0HVp8HUcR8EsYJLXDgjsQe4910phcASRyOCtaNVJSyLSDRu1FNBWkSwgAK90U7oKiIgitoogqoUWyKKSaQRxML3u6AcorLGxpsrJbBAwvceaHovpnh7QW6Jg/i2S48mQ4Av3AuPzACuOlWV1fhzQmYzmyS+Y6VwDqYBVg3R79u3VeqZNCbhbxzuLn00F3cc8qW4Sa3NjqF92C1tGQNDePQ7uf/3S4OdlCLFMkm4Or5WOJAb9h9ljNnO2hlA1156c+p6crqcqc5DnGXc1nQe4+qzuNSb4dXNly+cZfPmY5xBaGkjn1sdF7fwXkDLxNR0uSSR02XpuTju3kBrmuicOtcndRC8dNCYrc50myrO43wvQeDMqXG8ZYD4t8rJ3hxiumgWGjcT369E48tXs4Y+S/wAo+iLna3jRYXiXUcKEERw5UsTLHZryB/RcFbc07IqogIrSFBFFUQRERASlLFKoIVFVFQREQCsVkoVUqIiIjMJ7LG1bUaVLUS0wZJwsb5VCYCipUSArwp3RMGSiWogIiWqCdk7KWiaq2M5jcPuta2RdXf8AaVKrONod8rnUF2+LDhSwDzJZI4mDna7hx+lWumby1dngYbM57GiV0bh0B4s9kHb4zvC8U0YlycuR1i/JHlRgD1Lm36ey9lpOp6TJpsrdOkm3P+Vz2RMmkjPXc1wAd7WAvLQ+Hs0s/wCK1Y4DQ4OuUb2nj81Wey7/AAtMlnYciHWMLMjhBP4nGxxjv+W6JNBxJ569eFEatcgxczTGRmbOymsNDJLhJ5Q9wAHAH3Ar3Xb/AA+8SZ/hjxJhZ7vmDA2OVrr25sQPzNJ/KXbXVfegutzMuabGLy7MkfIC180pMg20OOR8tcLzOJqc+DqT8aan45/5jogAXN72Ol1fzD9VFlfrXUfDfhTxPFhZeXh/i9IzI9+Jk/zxH+aMnrbTxS8nqHwC8D5WHuwNQyot3XdyaH+vK0/CPxY3Ozp/BmS5rsXMa7JxHXQim5HBPI3V0XvmZDomnCkfVuuj19f9AmudmPzJ8XPhc7wNlQ5uG582BkMG2Q/ym6pfK6X77zNB0Hxf4fdoWvRx5MYjAHNOa72K+H+Of/Dv+Gjgm8IA5BJqVj3Vto0Sr7Wcs8V+daNEnhRfW9R+B3ifHxmeUYHybd74w/8AKe4/ouI34GeLDhnJc/FYLprS+9wur/qri/aPl9qL6W74MeIYtxmysMAO2Cn9XVf6UtGb8G/GWHhzSR4cWSY2h5EMlkgmqAUXY+eBVc/UNC1jSpzDqGnZGO8DkPYQuCWObRcCAfXhFTqa9VubjyO3kMJaz8xHNdv6rm6JpZ1DOb5rhHjsNvkPYe3uvpmJ4p8IeH9Hdp+NoUWb87ZDLOLL3A3yg+UjDmG4vieAOBx1K73SNPjiYJS4ulDuWgHnpwT2H9l32v8AijJ8RZ7pHafjYkco3+XixbSQBQJP2P7rVhtj8xu1ztrK2tYdzqHf3/0S0m12+LK7He4zMewDghho/v0/crHNyYwHPiY97epPBrv19UkzCzHaz8PsZXLpQSXHrxa6uSSRz3O2R7TwQYx/sLDpI15OW/IbbIpGRnsTf7rCOUyOZG5jmkfzF3JH07rYyI5Ee2tnqQKW6DE8htyneB0vqPosc+WR36uFta9QlYWDgW0Vwaul3/gzG/EiF4cwSfiYmtEh2mt1kj2rheZyHPnyfLjNtbxZ4pex8HYkONrkWSwtdEJdzXE8uYwbiaPQccFOqeD5XKa+WeKHxS+NNWkhA2uzZnCjfV54XUrZkyCbLlmAID3ufyeeSStNhdnkVOilogoKWsbS0wZWpaloTwgtqWp3RXARFFRUREBLREEtE4RERWkVQxindERBERBVQoiKqlpaiGqlqIiLaWoiC2oiqCqUqp3RVWyL8zh6tIWtVgLngBKrYw12W9jt7vmk2m+oNLS4106+qx3juDffgFQdxj5UmPFUbJnu6F7XNsC7468rv8bW5nudGJ8lrHBokZLbT6draf0XiAeflL79l3+CcuLTxFDmywPm/PHI11SDqLNEV9vdEdrmaxosURZJFM6Ytvzy1zXA30Ba4ADp27dF0ORmMyMgTwNeyVo3A7r3D3tcPJbJ5z3vygTfykDr96A9lYiSGNcCNvX1TB9C8H5+owa9g5WnR/8ANa0+WBZbKw20V6dei/QPijVmDXP4U0UZk/jujcfy7gCQD6WCAO1L81aNky6flxT4ziJGM3NHqeaIX0WPXH6vHFLqTxA+N1gMFg11v6crNH1Xw/n5j8OTKY/dlOPltjHV1uNfeqWeteL83THRaXj4cmVklji47qAofzetE/0XiNJ8UDSsyF3myHyXF4jvkNo1x34WnUPH2PNrGWwt2mWQOZK6htaANwPtbePspEsY694y8Xwac3Ojw8ZpnjdYEZsBxAog9+lfVfPtU8Y+LcXKmgGW9jIHEHZQA+n6lfQsrxHpDdJfm5JZMHu2RsksmmjjnjkLi4+Tomfp2qPkgifC4Fry4B0jztNfQXYr2V8Hp8mPibxBkbslupZRpxcTvPHHK5um/EDxNphLmarM7eWlwf8ANdHjr9V7ifw1ouP4GZg4cTTNMxsbnk08ucd1hp5Hytq/ddNqHgzBydNczTcYtnbGNrehAG42b6k2Oivg1M34vatm4DcfNwcHK2nl74rJXl9b8Sx6q1rnabhhw7sjA6dF1z9OliblNkG12LII3gjr6/6fqvUReHNPxtEE2VscXBvI9xX9atDI8PJnSBuxtRtu9rRQXOxcBseI7MzpP4rSNmOWkkg9He447dF3GJ4dxsnU5ZhJG6HHLi5zh8pd/I0361z7LjZMTzmh8p3Rtc5sLXDo08n5enUlVWGFF52SyKMbWkkvc0kD2v8AU8Lvon4GnYD207Inedxf5nlx0B0rhzv1AWvSsBwxhL5Lpy1t16V7fTv2WnKaZHGSWNponmWUHn2HYLFvl0nFxcnU8ieR7nv8x5d+ctJoelk9FpjnkmcAXhx73wVNvmSOFgk9guZFDJAwSDHsgcE8I3x9uyw2xxxtMrQSbFHhdbqGT/xHlRX6fRYufNKd1lo7+y4ssZe8NHW+/VcLx27ye3jyyZx9pGY3yFz4zIPy23uf9fqvV6RMzE8La9qMkMXnY2DIY3usfm/h1fY/NxS62bSTpmiNynP/AIrxuYehH0WGu5B0j4ROwz5gn1bKDacbqOMhzqPpu2/ut9XOc/M9PN8rrvXfry9vmnTi1CVFCu+PKyBTqsbRXEVRVRBVEQIAVUS0NVRVQoUVUCqAihS0VUUtVBEQpyiIiIiFK0iFAUVUQEVRBEVpEEVUVpAVUpVFgeFvfjNiZcuTFuIvYw7z+3A/VaECK2AwgfkkcfdwH+i2RuiDXHyRY/6ytA+q2RUXlh43cKAXwF3Mbx/2uv8AqFm10Njy5XN//sFD9lxyNriCVkGXzR6cqo7CPz44/M2N2Do9vzgn046I5809gSOIceSev29u9LjRfKQ+N+w1RIP+/wB1yIsiNslTDy3d3tHB+rf9R+hUHIxsOPYY3kOY7s40Qe1H0P8AZXYzGlG0+bEegeOW/wDSVxZshzZHBrqN2HNNgo6Xzy198yWHD0d1H69f1Qx2mNqDow0NeAwH5WnsO/26rtP8cLWloc5gr5a7Hv8AsvIxOJZK0jlvzV6c0f6rYx5IpzuWmvqEw17KPXZHOe4Skylopx7rrs7WHuyGSBxsg7Qe3+6XQ/iHhoAcasLa1j3yNsuq+XHspg7uTUZZ/LifK5wj59QCSP7fuux07VJJm/hi94iA3SBp6guFj7ml5UyVEXt4LjyfYf7C2Y2S8XICA0DaK4TB9Bk1VzcjGn85zImgPHNuJo1z7cAfRcnK19xzHZTZHB7ntc918H5W/Kb6crwkE0rsRjHONtJcOO9ELS3UDI2UEk8t4ur4/taYY9ScuNz52Oc1pyJbLQL70en0C5Dcv8Ti5WK1pfvB+VzgNpPNj0oALxIznCcEHnpYPcrmwam6Pc5rtoeCAfS0xXp26plvx3Yk74CJmbSGD89X6f1WAxWztjc0F0QOxri4mgenHsD+66EZMEsrXjq4Dnvfddtp2QRLG57C9rDe29oHPH19f0UI9Tmsm07RYIvLdAx7HOdtHLx6F/f6AUPVeHzclwkIa+O6FiuV9I1LI1DVfDeJqs7SI45PJbK4l20lvFjtdFeE1XFxGxl02VIWi7Nk8/RYvt1np1uLmlkhFAuPAK7vHGRO0NcY2h/HqV5sYLDgvyMeRwaCCHnoOar1XaYebLHjCR45rbvHS0vp16rLfLnZMLojtY6/Wu65WhaQ3N1OMygBgILrNBaYMhvkF0lEkrl6XmOiyA6N5FvBAP8AZebs5/0XXv6eu/uTlw855dlr8TXa1FixmSGCxtIHAA7heJ+KU8bPF8OiYzXRwabixw7Cb/iOG956+rv2X1nHGk+KMdgjz34eR5jWl/lkhjuhIrsbIPvRXx74qT+f8X9c+TYIpm44/wCoRsazd99t/ddPjcPpPrPTxfN7b28vvy9/h45RVRet4kV+6UrSAiIiooqVEZXuiIiqOiIiKid0KBEEVRDGKqFB1QCEr2WXCiBSizPosaQxE5VpEMEREUREQKSllSUpoxpFklJondWkpUdFBKUpZ0sSEAvcTZcSQKWTHOBHNLAqjgoN+Q9wkumkHmi0FYCYAgmJhr04Vm5o+y1dOiqOSw4sj6c98F9y3e39qP8AVWXEyBAZWbZ4m8+ZCdwH17t+4C4oBd0C2QTSwTNmglfFI3o5hohUWCbYSx7BJE78zehHuD2K5sMUMeS1k0n/AAs4IbOG1t54cR2LTVj0v1BXJxjpepM8rP26flkEtzGN/guPYSsH5f8AvZ07tPUY4jIsHWH6brsb4cSavMc0bzDY+WZlcOA68cOaSO4IYmtBgc3UHNe3aXgtIHIvkcfellLiGD+K0B7GAOJA4pw4P+i5OXDPgiTDlY38XiOLXua7cyQA7mva7uC2qrqGg91nC6HNe+BrNgdE41f5wbcPuCi7vl1OL/zzu6Ubvld3gwNniIIN7KcevPYBde/HA02LIZbi6w6hyKF39F23h55MsMe6muLXOJHvXX6/1UpHX5WMBvjY6jQsdx6/0W1+EYdMx3tFslibLZHUbuR9QVzdWZJDqkAdtcZW2ABzweePsu2MLZ9Bx4bLifylzeWn+Ztd6oH7BTR1UkIhna+y6nWWnsCAQullYGyudEKLeSfvwvVZMcMmPIOA4A2bvsB/VdNlYRZkbDdOI4ISDrZI3CnHg1u4/ZRri1rWn1F/YLmvgBDbBFAuo92g8LiFpc7dR+eiFVc7GcGFrnH5wBQ6kE9OO69ZoOlZ+vZkeDpeLPkSh4G1pALjXQ9rNHrwF4+Jzg8SFwL3dC3khx4/YL6X4N1nGiy/wckzMDRoeZnsaXue8/ICDVDrZsgfKeaWa1xd/nRTz/CvLypAHxYYa9mRy3yyCGuh6U/8xPBvoe9D5SMmUaflPe5riR8u35r5FD27/W19J+JWs/jtJyI8HGdg4HnNjxccyfM5jRwSBw9zgA4kANb0FnlfMsfGlyNO/CiV7Y3Stdtu2+5v7UpWrWeJ82mMhkry3PbI5l3xfA9Rdrflg+YyKGMhg43Rj5dxNk/c8D6LXkwjHcHxlrnA02jyT6n6c0soGyGcFoIDCS112Sa6/wBlKvG+WZmOM0CVtyV8rf8AKfddhpH8USOlJBaN1joF1byIJpHSx73Afzc0fdczGzI5McQNfI0Pppa1vX/fovP3dX344+h8X5d6eX2jvvDeZkN8WRNjc5rGvB620m+OP3Xlvi/JHL8YtYkjdG4l8e8s6F3lttfWvCej6dpmmSa5lyuix4AZfMeANxbyBXQX0X5+17P/AMU8RZuokuLsiZ8pJN9STS9HVwnGZHzu7svZztdYFkAgC2NaumuUjENWW0LKqWLiorByxVJUC1EE7qogndVSkQVL4REDuiIeqKIiIJ1KdlVUREREVkgCycFAsiUlLJRBjXKtcrKuUQYkJSyItSkADhKVV7IrHm0VpTuiAHCvoiiCoVAeVUEpZxRlx56LFboSKIQa5aBr0Wtuy7eXV6NWycc8BamBwd8v6FaiVyo34oFfhGvP/uSOH9KWRnxwdr9PaCP8krgf3tcauu5p+y5MEUb2Hc9rh/kPyu+oPREbY4MbIpsUskN//wAw3NH3byP0Xf4GmPl0wafqeQyOJhc7Fn3bxHfUtcOsf+ZvawRRu+jbhUdrJg9po7XENI+18/YrtdKzsnT5HDzR+Gl43vbuax455A9ao9D3BtRXJkxMqKHFgzI2N1HFcMfa54IyYv5KPT5Sdt/5XM7BdLp48rVXxRs3wuDo/mFOjvlpNdCHV+hC77VBi743PAbj04RNbM2Qxgiy0OHUXe26NUCOF1GDJu1nzo2iR5YXO3VTqIJP36kFW3Ukx6h+jYztDk/CMkDnxMeGuNAC6e0+osAgjsV0/h7Ts55yGw0HMfbrdW0AOcDXcEgj2XtcOeObRpWwRGR0eMBjtZY2gOAJ56Dmh16LrosAafIMxroh54c1zSOGgxl3B+r1nVdZl4Ddb8S6hEyQAYcbvLPfywQDt+m6124x3QTQafkPeDLtmhNbQ0uBJbfoQ53PtSx01+Jk6/JnsALWxOMgiBBeBwRt9xtNdy1eszdOhzNNE8UMUmNu82KSRzmGKvmeznmvm3D3JrglB5zO0SH/AAmTJikbujDQS5pBLXNAa6j6kg/el0us4ToNTmikeHeW+m7jtP5R2+gs+5X2bN0bCycNkeVCY4o8Z43Rv3NcN7iKJsjgAd6IK+f+NNPlh1qMCi+eMGV4JLt12D9S2un+VB8831HJJJ8o27AB9en7fuuFMx7KvbQHbqLXqcnRNrGti6uIppF2ff3/ALLr34REbgA3mhwTxd8foP3RXSRSiMtfzYNgd7K9BpkkkmLi4MAeZHz2WsdRIA5HPS7cL+q6bIxi1ziGhoBoHqFlj5U+LN50TnRyAUHdCPdKR9KbBpmfkT6bFHC6WDc6nPrdI8ioo6suAG4uc6ydtccBdpJkRYfg7M0rSo4sfAmia2XUMto8zIO7/wBNlEsAcOprvZXhdE1HJ0+J0olY3Ile13HWOujj/ax7rvsXOjEEWPq+syvgmeJHY0Tg9wPI3gEBrT2HBIHTm1n/AK1b48PIZUEzI2s6N6gvNWfX3H0tcfHeY5QJJA0D0FX7L3+r6VPrzvxvh3SMudpZvcI2ulcKHLnk3Q47key8DkY2RDnuZlM8qQcU8dD6K2E5NuU8NZQrnn1XbeDMYZPiuFj2yeTI0h0gA6nqPpXH3Xm8mVrwyNu9xcQG7RyT6L6l4C0XUNPlbmy44Ydx3mZvLaHUO6e39FMa58vw5Xxm/F6R4S0vTNNlnbiTRh07GNqOweN3oV8CcHbyD1X3f4nyZGo+AvNdMCI5OGHsB24Xwsjm6WnKMQ1Z9EqgsS5GhxC1OKFyxtWRNEQFFUEUVQVE7IinZERAV7Kd1eilEpFSgQRVEQFaCiWgyJtQIqoB6KKlRBkE7qBEGQUS+U7oKiIihUKHoiAeixKyUpERUIloKSs4fzWtXVboRQJQSTklYtjcRvptDiy4DlZPFnhajV3SsRujiMtuE0QI7OdyV2Z0fKEQlYCDtLnCUsjoeot3I5XTmaQkHd0FUBSB293z2UI9CIIW4QLM/Ga4VccsjT/9rgePv+q6zKy5A50Mcp2E8t3tePsQuJFD5h3XTVvMMYFbSfupbIs46wZNI5hYG8ey3QZLooXRvYHRklw4F2Oeq45YWGxZb3B7K0d3HTtyrpj2ul6sMnKw452SP8stZK4SWXijQ+3H2C7yeXLgc2XZHkvjeZS2xTtzW8AD+W+AelghfN8GRsedG5zi0AgAjtZ6r6Fg5fnYRyMmNsbaEUTnWCxpDyRftbePUkqUYaNnMwNWn0XMxXY2ZFMYZHvFeWDw5p7gh5H7he30ySLYwTzwPL55sLKhcfyO8s7X7e45cAe3HsvI6bouWcxuowQQvdKwHbuEge+nbo3XwDtLbJ70vbs03J828qXHERcZ8UGPY5lANc53YMN7TdgFv6So9piNxtVxZcd7o8TFdEPJkeSamL2l0Z+/PqOee6+c+JpcjN8TPY0P8yOV5BqiXA3tF89QR+vVeqgzzBjsiyoHsimjyT5AtrZDJT2ycn5qDv0De1rz8uA3LyY58kvDTbXuAIebBBdu6k2CDXFn3RHSPhORDQYA2TguDgA6uflH8o55J915rLa3yvKw3zvaRyWsAbz15PPRd9rur40GLNFiNL3tmc5szXfK1tGmV0Juz1Ir1XlYs+CVwdN8l/mY93mb+ehrp3/+EacbIwnQxNax/mOc0vA54+3TouH+Cf8ALsaHyHqRz+i9NCzdIZ25keyjYcTxxdcX9Pqrl6aZGl7WuaGEtrij9OOtJo6LHdOWGJrnMLncue/axvUX7912eNJpWJGY45nTyymnuc0OeQOdrWDho9XE2uuzMd0NFheGBt7d1Vz3FWuolyNrQ2IOYD6WEV7keIZhiOgOt5uLjAfJjYz3gyH0LmENA69b/Vea1PK02fLJw9MkxzZ3mbJORu9zdLq4pXF3zvJ9Cu0xIYMmQR2xp7ccH3VR23g3Ghf4kgynMme+Oi0RFpo/fovtbZWx6WA/HnPy7nlzBucT6kuP2Xzbw7osrWMeyYAF1WwHr9V9IwY58kRQxja5tbiX1Z/33USvO+K9AfneCMx3lRExglplbuoeoPqvz1I0skLTzRq1+pvFusab4a8ISt1ImOSZhbGB/ELvYWvy3lyNkyZJGCmucSBVKkaHOpay5HFYKyFO6IraqHREKIqIiqIqIiNCqipUBFLVHVApFeyKCIhRWCIqpaDJCoFSoFopSqCp9kHVWkE5VCIeiCkoseyt8Iolp2UQW0UVREKiyUKAtsTuCFpWcZ+dBk+7pYFtrNx+ZHEDoqNO3nqpdE0sjVLAqo7Ty/LY1nQV+1LizvIcACRZXIx8pkuG2CarZe13evqjsQylr2Oa70Frn6vlv3PDWfy3YWtnFj091m87LB7e60Qvt7ye6sZrafYr3nh/K83w4MNrngAtdK53IL3Oc1hPpQPovCWav7r3PhKKGfR3+fjTOMpL3SxtDaLX0Ab6gFzSPofRXB9G0rT8PKnkymOETt3z40Q2tLnWG2DYAoR83zu7L6Hj6P8AhMbGnndAc3T3tx3W4kBpjLXv4NfNcZHPJ5v5l1vhjQMxmPBmQQMdC4MdtkYLfTG9rFE7Xgc9Whexk0iXFzMgyBk/mSRCHKxzu2EvIJomvyBti66891GXktP0/MfnSY2L5f4Vjt+LHI8Oa3/lii51E2DG3pVtHZy8/wCOtSPhTw4ZsiXIdrOe97cfHaBbgXkX60av16L7ZjaM3GDsifEe7IbG9jonP2j5uAPexGOe3XhfI/hDp+l/Fz/xV67Pq0X4rF03T55cOB35SWPY3d+rj9qXD5Pb+zwvL8OvT1/ucsfEj4W8T6o5+RmYk0cbSXFrgQ1g5PDRyQKPK2w/DzWJsWSf8KQ2N4jdTvykmvpweCv1X4hw4NH8STtbhSY8wkazIdI0UweYH36H+Ue9c2vB/AvClyJvFWFkQSOxX6nPA9oZe0iS+nZfF4fqfZ2ceznJ/ZZ4/wC+3p7OPDhy48f8o+MZXgbxr4bwBrA0nMdhMNSPa4EDgOvjkCiOv62uZjZOPkYQymbj5gujbbrqLPFg/dftfWnM1fR5sDUcbHbjxYgxyIY2M3sAcTv7Od1snqvx1o2ZgZjtU8P4ksMunsyHGEhvMztjWcGj/MCR0r15X1Pi/JnfeUk9Z/44c+P1x5fUwzzfMa1w3AFx5se37Lz+VjHYXAOPcfzfr6L0mbh5ePlSSvhe1jjtcGjuOD/euPouBNHD5Uc0fD3d2kODiD1C9rk842N8dkNHof8A5XZ4Dzua8c16OpZTwteGu3hziOR0J90xBUzSwtHPQOFqj6BoEwa9m5oLhRALyAfuvsnh/Iig038UMeFlMq7HH09QvkPhwQb2W9zb4Ic4G/tX7L1Wr+JcfQtEka7JZ5rm0zazn2NHhRK+Z/FvxXneI/Ero5QWY8Hysa3gH3rovmbzyu01bLdl6pLO8257iSSuqlBDlonhrPVRO6KoIiICqiqCKhKRFZUoVQeEIUVAqoiBStIloCvZS+VVAUQogJYVUpUVX2RFAKInRAVukWJPKDK07LFXsgFFSFLQE+iIAgd0tVQoFqFEQRZN4NqIEG6txWLhwtjSCKpYuAHsg0nlYnlbCPdYHgFaRjZBsLMTPHdY/VOOxQHPLupWcPDisOFWmuURyAeo4C+j/DbDnzMHIbHDYEzXbw+ye5Dh2aKBv1IXziJj5HbWNLj6AL9B/wDh20CHUI9enzBC1mOxkfPUh+8EOsVR461+Ue6YW5H2Hw1pEztNa2PeI2sBZCH2x4I+YDuHOO+x1Bql6vGw/mGO7HM8TjwGPNPj3V39Lqj6m+65Oi6Dj4zMafGxoISIRt3NcKeGlvDruvrf99Goy4+j5pyJmkslZz5YJDX1tDj/AC7nN78ctrupmMy66zWpc2fw9mR4cb/Pe1x3SurlzSGNJ9QdxJ62V+T/AIGfEAfC/wCPWjeJdVOQ3Ex8h2NqTInU8wvtkh9y0/NXfbS/avhTydc0nLynywQmQPne6mSXEw7DxYu6/W1+evij8GfB2Rlz6t4W1CXTNRmcZXQvBdjSknn5TbmEk3bS4ewXm7Ov7/bjz9WPX1dk4TjePuV+mPHHhjE8SxxeIdCz4dQwM7H8xj8d4cydhdQe1w9aNj+y6bRvD2m+H9I1A4UEcT8iV88z2/MXTPABeR7lo+591+TfAXjX4o/DF8mLo+oYWTptnfgzZB8sHm9oI+XvYHC7LxT8ZPiH4jL8PHfg6MJmujkZpZc98rXCi3e7oCKFCl+a5/pHde2/S+L7u+Ln5j3zv6vrN/j148zf9vYfGz4uwafpeb4R8OTQzapm3HPkQF1Y8bmkPBv/ANQ2R7AnuV8m8G4g0yHEyY2nznv4fyNgHQ8Ec3Zvsuu0vwrkOmdlZME7pHAuHNucQf5jzXXovVzYzoS1s2TMwMbtEW0xPsdfm4977fdfovifF4/H65wl3838vnd3Z9+W+m3Uwx8nmMx4jPKS10Za23Xzd1RvldFnaLBJJshY/HeAS5rY79zYbwPpa52TJJK5jWuD4gxp2ybr60eQSD9qWD45W4swji8uN77Lj+aj2JP9vRelxeIzIJcfIIDnkHkbgRf2WvEex2QAWEOvof7hd3q0JOCHTStDeg4uq7LzsdRTEgkC1VfSdMlZp2jPy5p4y1rQ7YC3n9eV4bxF4jfquRtZflN4aD6LHUdb83TW4jJD8oqwKteckf8AK43aQcWZ5MxWp43C+6ONuJtGmupW0aj7qLa5oPRa6pBFQndVCJ2TuhQdUBFUQxAqlIgKqBZKKxVU7qgWgiySkUDuonZVARFLCCoiIHZE7IgqiBVACqiWgKK9+qhQO6oWKyCCqK2paCK3wpau0kcc+3dBiTyqFEtXBvj5b1WT6A6WtLHc9VuJ46AqDUeeFiR2W35d1kEe45WbcSWb/wCnqY/5Gfm/+3r+io4tKUthY7eWOaQ4GiCKIWJFcdVUYgWeOqzDbcPTuoB83RZ9GoPW+CNHw9VnyvxQLzE1rmwklgcLAcQ4cWLBor9BfCjRYvCo13Cy8e3ySxtx3sDxJupwoEHng9xXLl8M+HDzHkzva5xLXtds8uw89AA7sRuLvoF+r/BumTmCA5TWxunEcsmwjcRTgQ02S0O796HYFGOX4fQHFsek4TWNeYywNJa+qroTY+YdenIu1574nYrP/JP4xkr4IY2uilmMh3Q2LF0eac0H0FgrttXhnx8VphyI2PEYi2RuLWAHkUAQA0bSLvvZXn9UzsnM0fJxG4TsuLyW+bDQMbuO3HFC7s/yjkqWpHGcX6H4aIhzXGN+mw+WGtII2ua6S3NPG4Pvj0HSiV5nUPErc2CSTL2TMMVMLrO2gNw2juOLrr15C9OPPHhPRInvDHSwOgLpA4AbYi35QL4LeRfJ2/ZfK9VhyoN2MwyxStke6nhwL+K3NINAgV9evSws1qE+VoLyyOZ2O8SNNP2kbwDwdwb2+p6rzmoS4DXSiPS2vjaQ6MtjEpPrQIa5o/Wwq+OSGQzzxPkgYWgvbGLjf/3dAeOvy3YXBcIo5w3NizY43ESMcWh77PHQ8OFdbtRp07vPmJD8kgTNaxr3vDg7m+W3bifQg1wudHpT2xs87y3PLiWyQ/I0ULrjdzXNABdxBhwhzWvdHBHLG5zS2N25rh1vYPlFVyB+y7AaQ92UGuyorbWx2S0yhzQ0G2kG+3XbYCK6n/DNPilY3J/ENk2BznuBa0GrAqvXv+y15odkU1jvNextEGG2geo45+4XfT4WLjz7MnLjhe753A/LzXRrjX7DldDnyR4+PKXta4kEkEXXp0q/+5EeN1Yh0RjbHExv5j5bjzz3FLyWTO3lrCRz6LttW1Nxe5rTFISOHD8w+/X7Fecke4vO/r7joqrEudd3YWEjvlolUuo9PutTzwqNJPKt2KWJNqWey0yzv2TgrEEpyihHp0WJWdnusSCgiJaqCWloUQLVUCy7IIslj3VHJUqoqEIRNFRQoFApVS0QLVUHVPugtqd1jao6q4MlFVFBUUJUBVwZWooVQgoQq2oSoJSqlqqhadkRQEQqWrgz33+dod79D+qn8I9C9v1orC0tVGVN4qQfcFb225nW/ouMDXWj7FcmB8Y/NAHH3cVKQAKhBHUfouUzLx4nh3+FYT65qQyEH/8AMLXl5MeXmPyGYmPitdX8LGDmsbQrgEk+/VRXGe8veXSPc5x6lxslYWbXJysPIxXtjyoJIXuaHhsjaJHY12XH5HBCqMgAOVSORxfdRvTjhY2QSCUH3DwVpR03SsSKSIGIl8jmvABeXta5oJ/7mt4HQBfoLw7LJl6X5GNlOdK9oZI3zDuLvMIontbQT7fNwvyF4W8a6jgSQ42dmSSYLCTsIDy0kbbG72J69F9h8O/GXTsSCLH07Gi2sp1eWGPLz1IF9eTz0PBq6VrnZX6V1PHnZ4dmf5ZIY3ncC+2F1ltWLFEXzyvKaNgTZ2qGcSysLZngxMbvDhR3bqqiOPmAPYduZpPxZ0XO8Lsi1CeKCSYGFogsvr5QLA/r2pcPwv4lkyPEmoaVpum45xsWUCOeYbnTH5bsmgBfSulccqEej1TSXz+HYoMidwkxHyTwRNbRDWmwA2ze2wOOKI4C8HqWGwxuxZIGbHSeaCWBzidvQuIHoP0F12+j+Ishn+GwZEMe6UO8vynzbC03yN1gkg2LFWDR9vAeIsffpcsceTFpEgDHOjkp/wApsFvJLS32PI9As1qPJ6t4chkdi6phSyRukY4OlxZgJAGjoWWC72oE1fJXm3403+FMgcyDKkPDWNe0u5672kAuBA9OD2XrNV01mmSQQ5GoYsr8gh8LXztbTWm6ppIAP+Y1weFrwmnN1EPwh8srrkazIDttu9Q4EDj3Ua10E2LhF48yOMyfLflED1sNb6eo9fRatS1fHwseKAxiYAO2Fu6Pb1o0OQevBJ9KXsPEmDFp+l5ec7MM8+Te+KPoDZH8w4PHW18E1zXYIdSmdBmTv+b5S59V78cH0pMJ5eh1jxTnZGjubm5EZx7JAfucd1deTx9l87yvEeVI0xRu2EHirNfQri6lq+RqMh855cKoHp+q6miOAAPoriuRJkeY8yPfueeSbXHLrJKE+tFYE2etKijngdVrkI6LM/K3ra0ONnqrClhPsseitqsnCp6Kd0RVHorVrFVBjXKLLqoRygiqlLIUgioRWqUVCoqatRIMk6qBW1BFURBO6iyUVBP1RLUEVCitrQvVQ8KWhKmAlIFeyB2UuuFbWJSC2llYrIKoKgoeigRWSKJamIqBrT1e1v1tTqiopZ6PYfoVNrasyNHtyVWxufZFBo6uPACbmsP8Pr/mPX7IgWUeTQ91WlgPRx+9LXyTZNlEHJIsWKCjCWuBDi1w5B6UrA+OwJQ5ze7W8E/fstuVOJixrYIYY2XtZE319XHlx9yfpSjTjvBc9zi4ucTZJNkn1WPzDgi/qs6sKEPBoWkFB622lXsBFjkeqC6quFsbvc0lrCWggH0F9FBx2OfG4gEi+F63wlpEWqadqUz5nOngjDoYWu2+Y7cOOnPF8fuuCNM0p3hDIz5M2QajHM1seMwtLTHR3OPcUa/Vdz8OoMBusszc7zXQRgtmBva3d8u4BvUhrief0NKpuPpPh7wFnaxk42rY5GFp8ga5kMJ/NwCWkk9fm49Rx25/QnhzSsLD0fGZjADgGJ7ow1rTf/LsiiLNUbP0XmfD/jPQ3ZbMeHJ/CzyvAy2fLRhZ+eZkZG0kEtc0VZaCFzc3Kyocx+DJmb8SB0cEjccHfucQWzub1c0FwbfoRZ45WOf21h4y1EZeNLAZ4NPAlI82B5Y5pPTduI2nm656Xu7Lx+pQxHThh63lnIcxx2g5LHvc3q00Q2xf+bsefRcjO0iHUNKh0vUs/wDFRul/jvyZnSAvDiASHHjcDRNHa5tHqCusz9B0PNMOSM5rtkQbHGf4rmNHyhvruHIIqj0Wa3He4+fpmiZ+Jp3/AA1bhMIztBDXN4c1pBA5NFo9iu906TTNTxMjNiwszBkYCS8ROjjffO4hpodKvoaXz7Dl0fOl/DswzJlMc1sT6BAeAfkuQEWRW2+COOtLvNazdF8HaQ7JdkT6bktZcbmO8sSE8lruS09CRYb3FqQeJ+K3ibMwIjpuDN57WWx76L3DgddwsX9KXwebVJ5nkSY2HIL5DoG3+wC7bxFrR1vWps3Iy8l0he4iZrt4om+lBzR34XnpPMPInEw9Wmz+h5WmlfLE4UcZkZ9Y3O/oSVqPq2ytR55KzaO4P6K4KDZvr9E4Psm7/P8AqtbpDdDkKCSP7BYcq9eln2WPJWkXlTn2VBrqiIJaFTugqvZYqj2QUHnlD6qK9QixEUpUIKEJRKWVS1VK5VCohQdFaTogWqoFeygiIorBVL+qIqIloojKpaiIMuiXaxVRdVRLQIFcp3QqoCIiKKqIiC5AjhjZvyJNzu0TDZP1PQfufouOiDOSR0lAgNaOjW8ALWsgClIMaV7cKhrnGgCT7Lbs8kfMLkPQH+X6+6DANcwgu4sXXdbm/NQFknjjuVookmzZ/quzgjjxNK/Fy2cie24zQfyNBp0h/wD8t99x7KWDgvaWOIIog0R6Kij+bi+6AC6WbWHIymRsBBe4MAAvqaUVWRgguLr9PdbDI5mm7NzfL86yy+S4N4P0ANfdcUOLZDRsXwei3l7HRhp470PU/wCwgxMwdG0EE9q9l3Ok607Tnsja2owxzT2G5wcN5rqRfH0HouoZjvfIGsAskNAPF30+i7bF0aOWSOLI1CGJp2ukc359jCSLNd+Aa9HBUew0nxHhzNY+V5Y1kewN3n5CKG4ccXQPHa+nBXudO8T6fj+EWYb8iTIdkPf/AB4sl0jGRmMAxizuA3FgcP8Aq70vk2R4czcBs0bHxiRzwGi9zrY9zXAVx1HP2XGxtA1V7IxA4xsDnOsuoNPF39gnpnNfXNH1XS4/DbsWfCzm4DpAz8M51Sllja8HmywkD3b19u7xc1w1bTIsfA3OZtjEgf8ALLwDT2m63NPQ8XX1XyP/AMwDStOOEMv8VKW0x7XGonWbFfRzhX3XJb471LN8Oz/g5nQZkLPnpxt7HUKB9iBV/TuKmD7LqXiLwho2ljMLtjntEORj87YjZG3cLMYNHqNu7tyviPjbX/8AHdcM+Jlva9hc1svmUMll8OcOjXj8pFAGgeD16R/ijIzZnZGW+8lzXNleeWzg/msep7t6HqNrhZ6Cao33GS6FxtpvkH0+oSRZCUvMxc5oY/vtG39v7LBzmv5fQd2eO/1/uoXPIAPzehUNA9VVCCTR5T5WC7UMnFBaibPKDN7ye3HqFhXNhVvHRCQeao+yqJ1Q88jqiA0eERERECkS0QE7KK37IKgKidEGXCUoCqFF1eERRMVVEtLTBUUQqYKooqqIiIgJSK8IMERFWVUREBERAQIqgFEq1kGlFY91kBwsg1EMY0rtRUIAarQTi1lsPU00erjSCNaXO2saSfYLZ5TGH+NIB/0spx/sFjbA2iXPHoeB+irWNjiE0gB3fkj9fc+39UGwvEUQcxoYXctb1Nerj39guPdmyST6lYue57y9xJcTZJWcbWusufta0WT3PsPdBnF5XnM87f5W4b9lbq71fdb8iaXJkORKSBQZGy+GsHDWj2AC4g+Y10FWfYLe95c2Pd1I3V6dgP0CggoRPeepIYP6n/fupG90U7JGuLXNIcCOCCFy8mFkWi4Lw63zOle4AjgBwaP6H9VwTSijGOe9rGNtzjQHurO1keS+OKUTNaaEgFB3uFsjtsEkgbbwKH/S08F3+n3WgAc/RUciPMewi64FBdlHrHkxmNuxzXtaHUOODYv19V0hF/ZD+UDsEweyPiiGPBiEQLpHOuTe29rujqPvwfuV1mTruZn4s1ZXkyjbKGMaGiTbYPT+YdR6i/ZefDiH7h26KjhoA62mIydI99uc4kl+6yt2Jkux5JAHHZLG6J49Qf7Gj9lxnEDopfCo2brsmrI5RsvFHoeq1X3Cnf6phrYZC012WJsG+xVbyKKvQEEoMfqqQOh/VTtQo2seeqCuNHjhOoTt7f0SiO6IAKK9SogqiWloCJ2S0EVRRBUQqIKr3WKqCq2sURVRS0RFQ8KWqihREQEvhRVDTuiIisUREZERWkEVpZBqzDaCLjXSyDVeFL5QZABFjahKDMlY2pfCEoKsgB1tYBW0GW70AHv3U/6nf/tByevHcqONlAJ5WNos4onTSbW0KFlx6NHqUCOPzHG3BrRy5x7BWSTdTWgtjb+Vv+v1SSUFoijsRg3/ANx9T/vhYto8noOSiMh8rK7nk/Tst042zBvoxo//ABC1NO4knqVlI4mTce4H9FFjJ77ijbVbARd9bNrWHC+endOqh47ooXkuJsgnjj0WNDuqp7IitHPKpohY2OeFHHlUUmuLUFqEk80huqtBOpV5KA0KUtEX2UsK1YUIQXvxygII57Ke4Q8FBR0pD15U6FW+K7IHTsr1BSuEBo8ikUofRRU8nhRBCKKcqqIh2RE7IIqp3RAREQECIgIiIHdERAREQZWixV7oHdEIUQVVYq/dApUNS0tFWleilqWgzBChKxtEFJUUS0RR0S1LRBURRFVFFQa5/REUmhX6qWoq0FztreSUGTI3SyBra+p4AHqVsllaIvIgP8O7c4ii8+v09AsXPDYzFGeD+Z3+b/4WrsgLImmhv3KxqyqTbyfdBsiIWUlbW/MbqqpSJZPFqNMOPVXusTx0VHugtV2WJsnosi4D3UJJFk17IjEmhQ6p2tQGuaQuJCotCrKnbhTvygJtAqgor1PqpRRCz2VPqlcq8UQgxSlkRR9kqyi4VfClLKqH9fZS0AdFCnN3/sofVBPql+qdkRAIlcpSAn1URAVURAREQEREBERAREQEREBVREFRREBFVK90FS1EQW0tREBVREBERAVURBVERAV7KIgqyugWtPB6+6wRBU7IiBfKKK90G6Los3H5ei1x9FsN1Slaa9hJsq0hJ7LLt1H3QYVx7BYuKzJFfMFKB5PCI18qc2tpZxf9UHynkWVdMYbTSVQItbD8vP7LHv8ANX0QYHi6Sq4JVtvpwgdzwOfVBFSPmVF39lSQHdqUGPAV4s19VAb6lBwKQXqpwDXVQ9b7oeSqKVPsle6iAivXlEQUT+ivugiiqd0D2TsiIIiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICJ3VPXraCIiqCIiICIiAiIgIiICoUVHVBtjWbr7BYx9Fsd0tStNR68lVtA+qxJPVZDgdOUBzqPRQO9uVdwPBUJHRqBZ67ljuaBxZKjq72T6Kt23yDSIluceFSBVkkoXtHQKFxLaJ+yCcEBTp0VJtKPoqF8cKg31CIR6IJ1KK+9Ul8oInawn0RArlD3TuhtARPsn0RBPop7qoHdSkKICd0RAUVrhTugIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICd0RAREQEREBUIiDkM6LLqERZaa3KdQiKwYAkmlkQBwEREBweFk4DaURFaRzayoIiqROyysikRFR3CgPyoiIp5aFO5CIgdK90v5kRACNPNIiIdCiIgD1QoiLDspaIiKoiIBTuiIUPVTsiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiIP/Z`;

}
```

```css
div {
  display: block;
  transition: background-image 0.125s ease;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```