# Fading body background images when clicking a button (not background image on a div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For duplicating alerts, please read the whole question. I AM NOT SEARCHING FADING TRANSITION IMAGE BACKGROUND ON A DIV. What i want is a fading transition of the whole body background-image when clicking one of the buttons as show in the snippet. Making a wrapping div could be a solution, but not the answer for this question.

There are many answers for fading background-images on div but not on the whole body.

There are some negative answers from 2010, i guess there will be something new around. And similar questions with no answer at all,

I´ve got a good solution for fading the body background-color using jquery-ui.js.
But doesn´t work with background-images.

Adding -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms;
in each CSS class does the effect, but just on Chrome:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbqyjh95/1/)

Here is the example:

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass(); 
});
```

```css
body {align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}
body.class1 {
background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-10uYQ232GmA/VB2cCRa0pDI/AAAAAAAAGgw/m9nRdE1d-Rg/s1600/checkerboard-tile-pattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
body.class2 {
background-image: url(http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/WebDev/WebPageTiles/tilesTiles/tile_pattern_marbleTiles_bright_green_256x256.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;

}
body.class3 {
background-image: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-mCCWT2Qsqe4/UhHnOaJW7KI/AAAAAAAAFRo/4FHJyJdAeko/s1600/glossy-blue-ceramic-tiles-pattern.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;

}
button {padding: 15px 32px;
margin: 80px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 12px;
border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="class1">
<button id="btn1">01</button>
<button id="btn2">02</button>
<button id="btn3">03</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you ask the same Question again? What Answer are you expecting that is different from previous answers to the inquiry?

Comment: Because the other question was marked as duplicate with two wrong answers

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong answers"? What effect are you expecting to achieve that the answers at previous Questions do not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388118/trying-to-make-multiple-background-images-cycle-through-a-slideshow-with-css-and

This is on a div

Comment: How is current Question different?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497493/background-image-fade-out-in-jquery

This is different answer than my question

Comment: If you mark my question as duplicate i will not get any answer

Comment: You have not described what effect you are expecting that is different from the effects rendered at answers to previous questions

Comment: _"If you mark my question as duplicate i will not get any answer"_ - well imposing arbitrary restrictions to possible solutions is not going to increase the likelihood someone is going to bother to find you a new one ... _"Making a wrapping div could be a solution, but not the answer for this question"_ - then first of all explain why this would not be an option, please.

Comment: See also [How can I make an image carousel with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295085/how-can-i-make-an-image-carousel-with-only-css/)

Comment: _"Adding -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out 200ms; in each CSS class does the effect, but just on Chrome"_ - that is most likely because background-image is not one of the properties _specified_ as being transition-able ... https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties If Chrome wants to implement it as such nevertheless, doesn't mean other browsers have to follow suit.